# How to upload a MS flow package to another SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, power-automate, flow, sharepoint-framework

I'm new in MS flow I'm importing a flow package from a SharePoint site and upload into another SharePoint site.

Comment: Hi @VinitKumar, Does my answer below helps you in any way? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Comment: no there is no help

Comment: Any issue while following the steps? Are you still unable to copy/import flow? Are you trying to copy it in same environment/tenant or different environment/tenant.

Comment: no im using it to another environment

Comment: In that case, you can export it from one environment and then import it in another environment. check documentation links given at the end of my answer. let me know if you face any issue while following the documentations.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to migrate flow in same environment/tenant for another SharePoint site, you can create a copy of your flow using "Save as" option and edit it to reference new SharePoint site.

[image]

---

If you are trying to migrate it to another environment/tenant, you can export and import individual flows across environments with packaging.

OR if you have multiple flows, it is recommended to use solutions for flow migrations. You can use solution export and import in this case.

Check below links for more information:

1. [Export a solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/export-flow-solution) and [Import a solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/import-flow-solution)
2. [Export and import your flows across environments with packaging](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/import-export-bap-packages/)
3. [Migrate Flows between SharePoint sites and Flow Environments](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0mf45xKMG7M)